# How to create custom error when convert cart to order in Shopware6?

Tags: validation, cart, shopware

I'm trying to make plugin for Shopware6 that adds choice of period of delivery (for example, user can chose product to be delivered March 07 9:00-11:00). Problem is that can't be more than 15 orders in each period. So if used proceeds to make Order from Cart, and if period he chose has more than 15 orders, I must somehow invalidate form and tell to user to chose another period.
So I must:

- somehow subscribe to the event "user makes an order from card",
- check if chosen period is correct,
- if not, tell it to user and don't create an order.

Is there any way to do it? In Symfony, I would just add validation to entity PeriodOfDelivery. But in Shopware I cannot do it because controller is in Shopware Core and I cannot edit it.

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe on `CartConvertedEvent::class` event. You can get original and converted cart data from the event.
In subscriber, you can do any check that you need and throw a specific exception.
You can implement your own exception class. use `\Shopware\Core\Checkout\Order\Exception\DeliveryWithoutAddressException` as template. In your own exception, you can specify own error code and message.

Comment: Thanks,
There are two other questions:
1) how can I get Cart from event? I can't find it in Shopware documentation
2) can I get Order data in this subscriber? because I also want to save order id in my entity

Comment: you can use the following methods of that event `$event->getCart()` to get cart object and   `$event->getConvertedCart()` to get Order data (which are prepared for placing). Order data is array so you can get id from `$event->getConvertedCart()[id]`

Comment: But how can I show this exception to user? In prod .env it just shows message "Unfortunately something went wrong"

Comment: Take a look on `\Shopware\Storefront\Controller\CheckoutController::order()` action
There is a list of handled exception most probably you need to extend the list of catchable exception.

Another option is add validation rule here `\Shopware\Core\Checkout\Order\SalesChannel\OrderService::validateOrderData()` In this case constraint violation will be handled by controller action but you will not have access to order ID for example.